# Sox pipe to wav2png: FFMpeg equivalent?

Tags: ffmpeg, sox

I have this command I need to run as a background task on my server:

```
sox some-audio-file.foo -c 1 -t wav - | wav2png -w -o some-audio-file.png /dev/stdin
```

But I already have `ffmpeg` custom-compiled with all the right codecs (which was an ordeal and a half) and I'd prefer to avoid installing `sox` and having to go through the same ordeal again.

So I'm wondering, could I pipe my audio to `wav2png` using `ffmpeg` instead?  What would be the equivalent `ffmpeg` command? I've been Googling on this for a while and nothing I've tried is working.

Comment: What does this do ?

Comment: `wav2png` produces an image representing the waveform of an audio file. The `sox` command decodes the file and puts it into an appropriate form for it to handle.

Answer (score 1):

## Choose your pipe

Untested example:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.foo -ac 1 -f wav - | wav2png -o audio.png /dev/stdin
```

Alternatively you could use the [UNIX pipe access protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe).

```
ffmpeg -i audio.foo -ac 1 -f wav pipe: | wav2png -o audio.png /dev/stdin
```

### Notes

- `-ac 1` was added to downmix to mono since currently with `wav2png` [the max of all channels is used](https://github.com/beschulz/wav2png#todo), but this option may be superfluous.
- You can use any type of input that contains audio and that `ffmpeg` can decode.
- If you just want to output a specific channel use the `-map_channel` option ([example](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#Muteachannel)).
- Simply using `-` instead of `/dev/stdin` may work, but I didn't get to try.

## Visualizing audio

If you would like to create a video of the waveform use the [showwaves filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves).

```
ffmpeg -i audio.foo -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=mode=line,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Or use a combination of filters:
[image: screenshot of video visualizing music]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]avectorscope=s=640x518,pad=1280:720[vs]; \
 [0:a]showspectrum=mode=separate:color=intensity:scale=cbrt:s=640x518[ss]; \
 [0:a]showwaves=s=1280x202:mode=line[sw]; \
 [vs][ss]overlay=w[bg]; \
 [bg][sw]overlay=0:H-h,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=10:text='\"Song Title\" by Artist'[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

From [How to Encode Videos for YouTube and other Video Sharing Sites](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube).

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately neither of the pipe-to-wav2png options are working.  wav2png produces a blank image with only a uniform background color and no waveform.  Nice visuals though!